# Running powershell scripts from jar file

Tags: java, swing, powershell

I have created a small java swing app that runs some powershell scripts.

While running it from eclipse the scripts work well, but when i export my project into jar file, the scripts doens run.

Scripts are located into src folder.
It seems like if scripts files (.ps1) are not exported into jar file.

How to export those script files into jar file?

Comment: What makes you think that the scripts are not in the jar file? Did you verify that? How do you create the jar file in the first place? Also, jar files are basically zip files with a particular structure. I doubt that PowerShell is able to run scripts directly from a zip file.

Comment: Yes i have only packages in the jar file. u have tested that, i'm trying to run external files

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you're trying to tell. Do you want the PowerShell scripts inside or outside the jar file? If you want them outside, where are they supposed to be located when your application is deployed?